# How I set the BreakPoint in xCode when I want stop at a variable changes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, breakpoints

I want set a breakPoint when a variable changes. For example:

```
......
if(downloader){
        [downloader addDelegate:sImageAutoSaver];
}
......
```

I want to break the app when downloader changes. For I want to know who changes the variable.

Answer (score 10):

If *downloader* is an ivar and you're using Xcode 4.4 you can use debugger console. Place normal breakpoint inside `init` method of this class or in `viewDidLoad` (if it's a ViewController) or in general, before *downloader* is assigned. When execution stops on created breakpoint, type `watch set variable -w write self->downloader` in debugger console. You'll see `Watchpoint created: Watchpoint 1: addr = 0x092359b4 ...` message. Next, press continue button and your program will stop whenever variable will be assigned.

After variable breakpoint hits and you'll see only assembly, try to look through execution stack on left navigation panel for methods of your application.